# getJSON not displaying data with Web API

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api

if I run this code Fidler shows the JSON data coming back correctly but I can't get that data to display in my HTML page at all.  I'm trying something simple to start with showing the JSON data that is returned with a JS alert.  I can get this sort of thing to work in other programs I wrote but can't figure out why it's not working here since Fidler shows the data coming back in correct JSON format each time.  I believe that my code below only runs the very first line and then locks up.  Please advise, thank you.

```
        $.getJSON('http://199...:8010/api/values/', { id: '000101' }, function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (index, RevenueCenters) {
                alert(RevenueCenters.Total);
            });
        });
```

[image]

This is from the Raw section in Fidler:

{"Blank":null,"StatementDate":"20140228","MemberID":"000102","Chargedate":"20140218","TrackingNumber":"PAYMNT","Description":"PAYMENT CK:007591(1)","SalesAmount":"-874.00","ServiceCharge":"-874.00","PST":"0.00","Total":"-874.00","ChitCode":"PAYMNT","Signer":null,"Blank2":null},{"Blank":null,"StatementDate":"20140228","MemberID":"000102","Chargedate":"20140222","TrackingNumber":"192738","Description":"SNACK BAR           ","SalesAmount":"2.00","ServiceCharge":"2.00","PST":"0.21","Total":"2.57","ChitCode":"192738","Signer":null,"Blank2":null}

This is what is looks like in the browser if I just run the api call manually:

{

```
"Blank": null,
"StatementDate": "20140228",
"MemberID": "000102",
"Chargedate": "20140218",
"TrackingNumber": "PAYMNT",
"Description": "PAYMENT CK:007591(1)",
"SalesAmount": "-874.00",
"ServiceCharge": "-874.00",
"PST": "0.00",
"Total": "-874.00",
"ChitCode": "PAYMNT",
"Signer": null,
"Blank2": null
```

},
{

```
"Blank": null,
"StatementDate": "20140228",
"MemberID": "000102",
"Chargedate": "20140222",
"TrackingNumber": "192738",
"Description": "SNACK BAR ",
"SalesAmount": "2.00",
"ServiceCharge": "2.00",
"PST": "0.21",
"Total": "2.57",
"ChitCode": "192738",
"Signer": null,
"Blank2": null
```

},

Comment: Maybe the problem is in your handler or looping code. Could you post a sample of what the JSON looks like?

Comment: Do you have the non-parsed JSON? I'm not clear on how to interpret that image. Are you getting back a JSON array?

Comment: Firefox Firebug shows my response empty, but Fidler shows the JSON coming back.

Comment: Firefox Firebug shows 200 OK response, but the response is empty.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "your url here!!",
    dataType : "json",
    success : function(obj) {
        // your code here 
    },

    error : function() { 
    // exception here
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried this but it's the same results, the JSON comes back in Fidler but I don't know how to display it on my HTML page.